# Aeroflex gaisler (RTEMS with leon2 processor) can't send character over UART interface

Tags: c, string, pointers, serial-port, embedded

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ioctl.h>
#include <apbuart.h>
#include <rtems.h>
#include <drvmgr/drvmgr.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define size 1024
#define APBUART_databits 8

int writetoport(int fd, char *b, size_t count)
{
    if(!write(fd, &b[0], sizeof(count)))
        {
        //printLastError();
        return -1;
        }
        return 1;
}

int main()
{
        char a[size] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};
        int fd;
        fd = open("/dev/apbuart2", O_WRONLY );
        ioctl(fd, APBUART_SET_BAUDRATE, 9600);
        ioctl(fd, APBUART_START, NULL);
        ioctl(fd, APBUART_STOP, 1);
        ioctl(fd, APBUART_databits, 8);
        writetoport(fd, &a[size], sizeof(a));
        return 0;
}
```

I am working on Aeroflex Gaisler (RTEMS with leon2 processor). Trying to send a character over the UART interface. But I am not able to send the character. Below is the line of code.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ioctl.h>
#include <apbuart.h>
#include <rtems.h>
#include <drvmgr/drvmgr.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define size 1024
#define APBUART_databits 8

int writetoport(int fd, char *b, size_t count)
{
    if(!write(fd, &b[0], sizeof(count)))
        {
        //printLastError();
        return -1;    
        }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
        char a[size] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};
        int fd;
        fd = open("/dev/apbuart2", O_WRONLY );
        ioctl(fd, APBUART_SET_BAUDRATE, 9600);
        ioctl(fd, APBUART_START, NULL);
        ioctl(fd, APBUART_STOP, 1);
        ioctl(fd, APBUART_databits, 8);

        writetoport(fd, &a[size], sizeof(a));
        return 0;    
}
```

I changed my code based on the reply then also its not working.

Comment: Surely write calling write is an infinite recursive loop too?

Comment: I want to write the characters to the specific port (i.e. over the uart interface). so i need write function call. This function call which is given in the document to write a data over the interface.

Comment: Then you probably should call it something OTHER than the same name as the system calle `write`, since the compiler will pick your function over the system call, and you end up in an infinite recursive loop, which only ends when your stack runs out...

Comment: `ioctl(fd, APBUART_START, NULL);` looks fishy. Use 0 instead of the `NULL` macro. Also, you don't check any return value from the system calls open() and ioctl(). That's the first thing to do if code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks recursive, all I would expect is a buffer overflow.

The code inside your `write()` is strange too, the address of the local argument is not very interesting, and the size is re-computed to be just the size of the local argument holding the caller's size, that can't be right.

If this system runs a kernel and has a POSIX-like library as it looks like, I'm not sure why you're re-implementing `write()`.

Comment: I want to write the characters to the specific port (i.e. over the uart interface). so i need write function call .

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your function signature, you seem to be after the actual [write](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write)  function.

If you're trying to have your own custom function that calls `write`, don't call it `write` as otherwise it will keep recursively calling itself until you get a stack overflow.

Call it for example `write_to_port`, have `write_to_port` call `write` and if the call is not successful add some error handling (as you currently seem to do).

Maybe something like:

```
int write_to_port(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count)
{
    if (write(fd, buf, count) == -1)
    {
        /* add some error handling */
        return -1;
    }

    return 1; /* all good */
}
```

Also, to use `write` you will need to include the `<unistd.h>` header.

Comment: write_to_port(fd, &buf[size], size_t(buf));    then I should include the above line in a main function.

Comment: Yes, define `write_to_port` similar to what I wrote and then just call it in `main` with the right parameters. But most importantly among your includes put `#include <unistd.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

In your call to write_to_port you are passing the address of the location following the last piece of your data, rather than the location of the first piece.  Don't put the size in brackets there.

You also seem to still have the problem mentioned by unwind, of mistakenly using 'sizeof(count)' instead of 'count' itself.

Comment: Looks unchanged to me, please update your question with your most recent code attempt.